# Nuxt.js : combine transition(to, from) and enter / leave events

Tags: vue.js, transition, nuxt.js

So I have this code, it decides what to do on a transition between two pages and it works well :

```
export default {
  transition: {
    mode: 'out-in',
    css: false,
    beforeEnter (el) {
      console.log('set transition');
    },
    enter (el, done) {
      console.log('enter transition');
      done();
    },
    leave (el, done) {
      console.log('leave transition');
      done();
    },
  }
}
```

Now I would like to specify what to do depending on what the next page is. So I've to use the `transition(to, from)` method according to the [documentation](https://fr.nuxtjs.org/api/pages-transition/). But unfortunately I can't mix this function with parameters like `mode: 'out-in'` and I can't manage to call the `leave(el, done)` function with the `to, from` parameters.

Does anyone knows how to combine this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you found the solution, but I managed to combine transition with routes (to, from) and the object transition.

Let me explain :

If you look a the *TypeScript* declaration for vue, especially the ComponentOptions interface (`node_modules/@nuxt/types/app/vue.d.ts`)

Here's what we have :

```
declare module 'vue/types/options' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars,@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
    asyncData?(ctx: Context): Promise<object | void> | object | void
    fetch?(ctx: Context): Promise<void> | void
    fetchKey?: string | ((getKey: (id: string) => number) => string)
    fetchDelay?: number
    fetchOnServer?: boolean | (() => boolean)
    head?: MetaInfo | (() => MetaInfo)
    key?: string | ((to: Route) => string)
    layout?: string | ((ctx: Context) => string)
    loading?: boolean
    middleware?: Middleware | Middleware[]
    scrollToTop?: boolean
    transition?: string | Transition | ((to: Route, from: Route | undefined) => string | Transition)
    validate?(ctx: Context): Promise<boolean> | boolean
    watchQuery?: boolean | string[] | ((newQuery: Route['query'], oldQuery: Route['query']) => boolean)
    meta?: { [key: string]: any }
  }
}
```

The transition attribute is defined as follow :

```
transition?: string | Transition | ((to: Route, from: Route | undefined) => string | Transition)
```

So, by using the function approach, you must give either a string or a Transition object.

Example :

```
transition(to, from) {
  if(!from) {
    // returns a string
    return 'my-custom-css-animation';
  }

  // returns an object Transition
  return {
    name: 'custom',
    appear:false,
    css: false,
    beforeLeave() {
      // before leave hook
    },
    leave(el, done) {
      // leave hook

    },
    beforeEnter(el) {
      // before enter hook

    },
    enter(el, done) {
      // Enter hook
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pageTransition` instead.

And did you try with a function?

```js
export default {
  pageTransition (to, from) {
    if (!from) { return 'slide-left' }
    return +to.query.page < +from.query.page ? 'slide-right' : 'slide-left'
  }
}
```

Doc here: https://fr.nuxtjs.org/api/pages-transition/#fonction

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using this code, but how can I combine this fonction with my leave event function? How can I get the 'to' value of my pageTransition function inside my leave (el, done) function ?

Comment: In the Nuxt config, "pageTransition" does not seem to work if it is a function. Not sure why. It only works if it is an object.

Comment: @Mig I use this code in a page, not in nuxt.config.js. Which version of nuxt do you use?

Comment: @ManUtopiK it works for me in a page as well, although the property is called "transition" then. But in Nuxt.config.js with the global "pageTransition" equivalent, I can only use an object. Functions don't work there afaict. My version is 2.13.3.